# Using an arrayList to create a menu and using a text file as input(bufferedReader)

Tags: java

As you can see below I tried creating a switch case for choices
1. Name
2. Course then Name
3. Year Level then Name
4. Course then Year Level and the Name
5. Exit
I don't know how to use switch case so that I could sort everything according to the menu. I will be using comparable and I am only allowed to edit the method called compareTo. My mind is blank and I got no idea where to start.
20192215
Ang
Bryan
m
BSCS
4
20192200
Santos
Charlie
m
BSIT
2
20192452
Chua
Leah
f
BSIS
4
20190012
Yee
John
m
BSCS
2

These are the inputs from text file

````
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Vector;

    public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            try {
                 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c://student.txt"));
                 char g;
                 int yl, I;
                 String ln, fn, id, cors, con;
                 Student v[] = new Student[4];
                 Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
                 boolean en = true;
                 boolean ent = true;

                for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                    id = br.readLine();
                    ln = br.readLine();
                    fn = br.readLine();
                    g = br.readLine().charAt(0);
                    cors = br.readLine();
                    yl = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                
                    v[i] = new Student(ln, fn, id, cors, g, yl);
                 }

            while(en == true){
                System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("1. Name");
                System.out.println("2. Course then Name");
                System.out.println("3. Year Level then Name");
                System.out.println("4. Course then Year Level and the Name");
                System.out.println("5. Exit");
                System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Choose Menu: ");
                int choice = sc.nextInt();
                switch(choice){
                    case 1 :
                        Arrays.sort(v);
                        display_array(v);
                    break;
                    case 2 :
                        Arrays.sort(v);
                        display_array(v);
                    break;
                    case 3 :
                        Arrays.sort(v);
                        display_array(v);
                    break;
                    case 4 :
                        Arrays.sort(v);
                        display_array(v);
                    break;
                    case 5 :
                        en = false;
                        System.out.println("\n\n \nTHANK YOU FOR USING THE PROGRAM!!");
                    break;
                }
                if(en != false){
                    System.out.println("Press [Enter key] to continue");
                    try{
                        System.in.read();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.err.println("File not found");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Unable to read the file.");
            }
        }
        public static void display_array(Student arr_v[]) throws IOException{
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
            for(int i = 0; i < arr_v.length; i++){
                arr_v[i].display();
            }
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
        }
    }```
        ```
        public class Student implements Comparable {
            private String lastname, firstname, studentid, course;
            private char gender;
            private int yearlevel;

        public Student(String ln, String fn, String id, String cors, char g, int yl) {
            lastname = ln;
            firstname = fn;
            studentid = id;
            course = cors;
            gender = g;
            yearlevel = yl;
        }

        public int compareTo(Object anotherObject) {
            Student anotherStudent = (Student) anotherObject;
            int compareResult =         
            this.course.compareTo(anotherStudent.lastname); 
            if(compare )
            return 0;  
        }
        public void display() {
            System.out.printf("ID: %-8s  Name: %-20s  Sex: %c  Course: %-8s  Year: %d\n", studentid, (lastname + ", " + firstname), gender, course, yearlevel );
        }

        public void setGender(char gender){
            this.gender = gender;
        }

        public char getGender(){
            return gender;
        }

        public void setLastname(String lastname){
            this.lastname = lastname;
        }

        public String getLastname(){
            return lastname;
        }

        public void setFirstname(String firstname){
            this.firstname = firstname;
        }

        public String getFirstname() {
            return firstname;
        }

        public void setStudentId(String studentid){
            this.studentid = studentid;
        }
    
        public String getStudentId(){
            return studentid;
        }

        public void setCourse(String course){
            this.course = course;
        }

        public String getCourse(){
            return course;
        }

        public void setYearLevel(int yearlevel){
            this.yearlevel = yearlevel;
        }

        public int getYearLevel(){
            return yearlevel;
        }
    }```
````

Comment: Line 42 in file `Main.java` is throwing an exception. Please [edit] your question and indicate which line is line 42 in file `Main.java`. Also, I couldn't find the code for method `display_array()`.

Comment: Sorry i just added my display array code @Abra

Comment: It throws exception, because you are sending String as parameter to Integer.parseInt(String s) method and the String's content can not be parsed to Integer. Since we do not know which line is 42 it throws exception somewhere where you call Integer.parseInt()

Comment: yl = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); this is my line 42 @Wortig

Comment: Is it because of my for loop?

Comment: `new Student[Integer.parseInt(br.readLine())]` but your first line is `20192215`!!!

Comment: I shouldve used size inorder to fill it correctly it was my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public final class Student {

    private final String id;
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final char gender;
    private final String course;
    private final int yearLevel;

    public Student(String id, String firstName, String lastName, char gender, String course, int yearLevel) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.gender = Character.toUpperCase(gender);
        this.course = course;
        this.yearLevel = yearLevel;
    }

    public void display(PrintStream out) {
        out.format("Name       : %s, %s\n", lastName, firstName);
        out.format("Student ID : %s\n", id);
        out.format("Course     : %s\n", course);
        out.format("Gender     : %s\n", gender);
        out.format("Year Level : %d\n", yearLevel);
    }

}

public static void main(String... args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("c://student.txt");
    List<Student> students = readStudents(file);
    display(students);
}

private static List<Student> readStudents(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(file)) {
        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            String id = scan.next();
            String lastName = scan.next();
            String firstName = scan.next();
            char gender = scan.next().charAt(0);
            String course = scan.next();
            int yearLevel = scan.nextInt();
            students.add(new Student(id, firstName, lastName, gender, course, yearLevel));
        }

        return students;
    }
}

private static void display(List<Student> students) {
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("1. Name");
    System.out.println("2. Course then Name");
    System.out.println("3. Year Level then Name");
    System.out.println("4. Course then Year Level and the Name");
    System.out.println("5. Exit");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------");

    students.forEach(student -> {
        student.display(System.out);
        System.out.println();
    });
}
```

Comment: I edited my previous question. I would like to ask for pointers.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

All programmers need to learn how to debug their code. If you are using an IDE then I recommend that you learn how to use its debugger.

You have some calls to method `readLine()` that you do not need. In the below code, I have marked these lines as comments. I also incorporated the methods `display_array()` and `main()` into class `Student` just so everything would be in the one class, but you don't have to do that.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Student {
    private String lastname, firstname, studentid, course;
    private char gender;
    private int yearlevel;

    public Student(String id, String ln, String fn, char g, String cors, int yl) {
        studentid = id;
        lastname = ln;
        firstname = fn;
        gender = g;
        course = cors;
        yearlevel = yl;
    }

    private static void display_array(Student[] v) {
        for (Student s : v) {
            s.display();
        }
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Name      : " + lastname + ", " + firstname);
        System.out.println("Student ID: " + studentid);
        System.out.println("Course    : " + course);
        System.out.println("Gender    : " + gender);
        System.out.println("Year Level: " + yearlevel);
    }

    public void setGender(char gender){
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public char getGender(){
        return gender;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname){
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getLastname(){
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname){
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setStudentId(String studentid){
        this.studentid = studentid;
    }

    public String getStudentId(){
        return studentid;
    }

    public void setCourse(String course){
        this.course = course;
    }

    public String getCourse(){
        return course;
    }

    public void setYearLevel(int yearlevel){
        this.yearlevel = yearlevel;
    }

    public int getYearLevel(){
        return yearlevel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c:\\student.txt"));) {
            char g;
            int yl;
            int i;
            String ln;
            String fn;
            String id;
            String cors;
            Student v[] = new Student[Integer.parseInt(br.readLine())];
//            br.readLine();
            for (i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
                id = br.readLine();
                ln = br.readLine();
                fn = br.readLine();
//                g = (char) br.read();
                g = br.readLine().charAt(0);
                cors = br.readLine();
                yl = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
//                if ((br.readLine()) != null)
//                    br.readLine();

                v[i] = new Student(id, ln, fn, g, cors, yl);
            }
            display_array(v);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("File not found");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to read the file.");
        }
    }
}
```

I also changed file `student.txt`. According to your code, the first line of the file needs to be the number of students in the file. In the sample file in your question, there are four students.

```
4
20192215
Ang
Bryan
m
BSCS
4
20192200
Santos
Charlie
m
BSIT
2
20192452
Chua
Leah
f
BSIS
4
20190012
Yee
John
m
BSCS
2
```

Comment: I am only using NetBeans Sir pardon. Sir, what would be the best ide for beginners like me?

Comment: @DominicSymonLee NetBeans is fine.

Comment: Thank you very much  Sir for helping me @Abra